# C & Lua: luaL_dostring return value

Tags: c, lua

in my C file I call luaL_dostring like this:

```
luaL_dostring(L, "return 'somestring'");
```

How do I read this return value in C after this line?

Thanks.

Edit:
Thanks for the help.

I'd like to add that to remove the element after retrieving it, you use:

```
lua_pop(L, 1);
```

Comment: [Related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12528820/lual-dostring-puts-nothing-on-the-stack). This doesn't work in all Lua versions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The value is left on the Lua stack. In order to retrieve the value, use one of the `lua_toXXXX` functions, with -1 as the index argument (-1 refers to the top of the stack). Alternatively, use `lua_gettop()` to get the size of the stack.

In your case, use this:

```
luaL_dostring(L, "return 'somestring'");
const char * str = lua_tostring(L, -1);
```

Comment: "The value is left on the C stack." should read "The value is left on the Lua stack."

Comment: This is not correct, you are ignoring the return value of `luaL_dostring`. I posted [an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33580406/1127972)

Comment: And yes I realize the ambiguity of the "return value" from `luaL_dostring` vs the return value of the executed Lua code. Regardless, you should not ignore error returns.

Answer (score 2):

The documentation says `luaL_dostring` does have a return value, which is zero on success:

> #### luaL_dostring
>
> Loads and runs the given string. It is defined as the following macro:
>
> ```
>  (luaL_loadstring(L, str) || lua_pcall(L, 0, LUA_MULTRET, 0))
> ```
>
> ***It returns 0 if there are no errors or 1 in case of errors.***

Robust code should check for 0 return value.

Strictly speaking, the macro expands to a boolean value, which is `true` if there was an error, in C++. This might be significant in something like a unit test.

Comment: The return value, in this question, is the `'somestring'` that was returned by the executed Lua code.