# Lua Interpreter Question

Tags: c, lua, interpreter

How do I get the output from the following:

```
lua_pushstring(L,"print(i)");
lua_call(L,0,0);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to run arbitrary Lua code from C, what you need to use is `luaL_dostring`, as in this question: [C & Lua: luaL_dostring return value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3677792/c-lua-lual-dostring-return-value)

**Edit: please note that Lua's default `print` function will still print its output straight to the console. You will need to redirect stdout in some way (probably to a pipe) if you want to capture its output.**

Answer (score 2):

That code shouldn't work at all. You're attempting to call a string. You need to push a function value onto the stack, *then* call `lua_call`.

```
lua_getglobal(L, "print");          // push print function onto the stack
lua_pushstring(L, "Hello, World!"); // push an argument onto the stack
lua_call(L,1,0);                    // invoke 'print' with 1 argument
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean the return value, it will be on the top of the stack.

If you meant the output from the print statement... that's a bit more difficult. The [suggestion I read here](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3aFTqdtgNb440J%3awww.idevapps.com/forum/showthread.php%3Ft%3D2386+lua+standard+out&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&client=firefox-a) is to replace `print` with a custom function that does what you need.

Of course, this is a bit complex, and I haven't touched lua in a while...

Comment: I'd like it to give me the output like how it's done in the Lua Stand alone interpreter.

Comment: That doesn't clarify the question. You mean like how it prints text to the console?